# Async function with callback

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm working on code that contains async functions with callbacks, i.e.

```
async getData(options, callback) {
```

I really can't think of a reason why anyone would use callbacks in an async function. So I'm thinking about rewriting it to return the Promise without a callback.

I'm asking this question just to be sure. Is there a valid reason to write code like this (that I don't get). I don't want to offend my coworker, but at the same time, I don't like seeing overcomplicated code that checks for whether callback is not undefined and returns the callback (and at some spots even does different logic based on that).

Comment: The only reason I can think of is to preserve older signature that just took a callback and newer code could use the promise. It just saves some refactoring. But it's also valid to completely remove the callback if you can safely change all calling places.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what the callback does. For instance, `getData` might have several steps, and the callback is fired after one step is complete, and the promise is resolved after all steps are complete.

Comment: The callback could be completely separated from wherever it's called. If you remove the callback parameter, it would be impossible to refer variables outside of the scope of the getData function. Async/await and callbacks are not "coupled" like that. I.e.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the callback is for.

If it's just to report the asynchronous completion of the function's work, then there's no reason for it — `async` functions do that with the promise they return.

But if it's for a *different* reason, it can be valid. For instance, an `async` function that copies data from point A to point B might accept an optional callback that transforms a record of that data in some way: The `async` function reads a record from point A, passes it through the callback, and rites the result to point B; the promise the function returns is for the entire operation. (Not the best example in the world, you might write that as a pair of `async` generators instead, but...)

I had reason recently to write this odd-looking duck:

```
function nextFrame(cb) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            cb();
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

...so that I could do this in an `async` function:

```
await nextFrame(() => {/*...updates for frame here...*/});
```

I can't just make it

```
await nextFrame();
// ...updates for frame here...
```

for a couple of reasons (because the [processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model) means my subsequent code wouldn't be run before the frame, and because I wouldn't want **all** of the work following it in my `async` function until the next `await` to be just prior to the frame being drawn).

---

Additionally, @VLAZ makes a very good point in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198074/async-function-with-callback/62198173#comment110003281_62198074), if an API previously supported callbacks for completion where the function didn't previously return anything, it can be retrofitted to return a promise but still accept a callback. One of the MongoDB client libs did that IIRC.